# Update Live currency rate in Odoo 10 or 9

Tags: odoo

I was looking for a way to update currency automatically in Odoo.

I have already gone through the official odoo link.

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/9.0/accounting/others/multicurrencies/how_it_works.html#live-currency-rate

But I still don't find an option to turn on automatic currency update.

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the views. It should be Enterprise Odoo, because the is an enterprise feature. After activating multi currencies you should see the new option under Settings/General Settings.

Comment: yes, I got to know later that it is an enterprise feature. Also checked on Enterprise Setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a module named `currency_rate_update`. Using that you can set time when the currencies are updated based on your base currency. This module was for Odoo 8 but it can be migrated easily.

Comment: I tried with it, i set up for `11.0` and i did the action manually but it does not update it, why?

Answer (score 2):

Its an Enterprise Option. If you are enterprise and you want convert from EUR to US, you must put the BASE CURRENCY of the company in EUR.

Then in the Price List "on the sales module" you must put the Price List on Us. so the system will convert to US to the public of the price list.